# php explode function not executing on the page

Tags: php, explode

Trying to create a list view on the page, which has content like

1.Make

2 Model

3 Description

There are almost 150 such makes, and respective model and short description are added on the list view through pagination - of around 15 or 20 items

I am trying to count respective listing on the page and in between create a lead form view after 7th and 12th listing on every page

However - though all the listing are shown in the page - but the explode function is not executing - no such lead view showing after 7th and 12th listing

Here is the code tried through php explode function in which

```
<div class="pageing-box-right box-number">
    <div class="pagination pageing-container"><ul>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?></ul>
        <ul><?php //echo $this->pagination->getLimitBox(); ?></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
    <?php $canEdit = $user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_toys'); ?>
        <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)) : ?>
        <?php $class = ($canChange) ? 'active' : 'disabled'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

<h3> <?php echo $this->escape($item->n_make); ?>  <?php echo $item->n_model; ?> </h3>
<p> <?php echo $item->n_month; ?>   <?php echo $item->n_year; ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $item->n_short_description; ?> </p>
<hr/>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
    $listings = explode("<hr/>", $item->n_make);
    $numberOfListings = count($listings);
    $Reset =1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i) 
    {
        if ($Reset == 7)
        { ?> 

        <div style="margin: 0 500px 5px 12px; float: left;">

        <p> Test create form view 1 of lead </p>

  </div>

   <hr />

<p></p>

   <?php } if ($Reset == 12) { ?> 

   <div style="margin: 0 500px 5px 12px; float: left;">

   <p> Test Create Form View 2 of lead </p>
        </br></hr>

   </div>

   <hr />

<p></p>

    <?php }
         echo $listings[$i] . "<hr/>";

         if($Reset>15){
                $Reset =1;
          }
          $Reset++;

    }
    ?>
```

I believe the problem is in this line in the below code

```
 $listings = explode("<hr/>", $item->n_make);
```

Can some one help on it

Here is the listing view - see the lead view which i wish to incorporate after 6/7th listing

```
Fisher Soft Toys
August 2016
Fisher toys are available at Bernado Store @ 10% Discount
-------------------------------------------

Trudi Soft Toys
August 2016
Trudi Peppy Bear now available. First Order will get first delivery
----------------------------------------------

Hamleys Princess Girl
August 2016
Hamleys Princess girl long awaited is now available online
-----------------------------------------------------------

Acctu
August 2016
Acctu Toys now available for sale in Japan
---------------------------------------------

Bernado Soft Toys
August 2016
Bernado toys are available at Bernado Store @ 10% Discount
-------------------------------------------

V Soft Toys
August 2016
V Bear now available. First Order will get first delivery
----------------------------------------------

**Lead View**
Send you Inquiry now by calling up 001 - 9999999999 or email on - xyz@yahoo.com
 ------------------------------------------------ 

Jo Princess Girl
August 2016
Jo Princess girl long awaited is now available online
-----------------------------------------------------------

Acctu
August 2016
Acctu Toys now available for sale in Japan
```

Comment: Do an echo of `$item->n_make`. Does it contain '`<hr/>`'s?

Comment: Did echo, no it does not contain </hr>. However when used - $listings = explode($item->n_make);without it showing error - Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in . Also - no change on page list view related to explode

Comment: What does `$item->n_make` contain, and ultimately what are you looking for?

Comment: Hello,. It contains name of make toys like - Fisher, Vombo, Jagoora, Zoom   etc i.e different brand of toys. What i am looking at is - to show a lead form view after 7th and 12th listing on the page. Every listing contains make, model and short description of 50 words

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the exact output, and what you'd like to get from that output. (ie. "<p>XYZ</p>", "<p>ABC</p>"). I'd like an array of values XYZ and ABC.

Comment: Hello, edited the question

Comment: You didn't say what you'd like to get from that. I'm assuming `array('Fisher Soft Toys', 'Trudi Soft Toys', 'Hamleys Princess Girl', etc...)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120338/discussion-between-frankerz-and-ruchika).

Answer (score 1):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/hH2hC1/1) to find what you're looking for:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\s+(?:January|Feburary|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4}/", $item->n_make, $matches);

$listings = array_map($matches, function($match) {
    return $match[1];
});

//$listings should be an array looking like:
//array('Fisher Soft Toys', 'Trudi Soft Toys', 'Hamleys Princess Girl', etc...)
```

Comment: Thanks, any line to be removed, where exactly should this come in